External mount for Solr schema.xml with docker
I'm using Solr with docker (used by a custom ecommerce website) I would like to be able, from a script, to update the schema (done by my website) and then reload the core via the Solr API.
However, I can't manage to share this file with a bind mounted volume. I get a permission error since my local user is different from the one who runs Solr in the container.
From now, I use a script at startup that :

leverage precreate-core script from solr-docker. It copies conf files from my bind mount to the SOLR_HOME (in this case /var/solr/data)
copy protwords, stopwords, etc... from the default core to my core named wg

It's work like a charm at startup but I can't find a way to make this on the fly.
Thanks for your help !
Here is an extract of docker-compose.yml:
  solr:
    image: wg_solr
    build: solr_conf/
    ports:
      - 8985:8983
    volumes:
      - ./solr_conf/configure.sh:/configure.sh
      - solr_data:/var/solr
      - ./solr_conf/${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}:/wg/conf
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:8983/solr/wg/admin/ping | grep \"OK\" || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
    command: 
    - /configure.sh
    - wg
    - /wg/conf

configure.sh startup script
 #!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
source run-initdb

CORE=$1
default_config_dir="/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf"
coresdir=/var/solr/data
coredir="$coresdir/$CORE"

precreate-core $CORE $2

echo "Copy default config from $default_config_dir to $coredir"
cp -rp "$default_config_dir/lang/" "$coredir"
cp -rp "$default_config_dir/protwords.txt" "$default_config_dir/stopwords.txt" "$default_config_dir/synonyms.txt" "$coredir"

solr-create -c wg

